# trying to export the pl/sql script exctract to excel file which is currently extracting the data and putting it in text file

Tags: excel, csv, plsql

I have a PL/SQL script which generates a text file currently, but I need to generate excel file from the script. I have currently have pl/sql code like below,

```
BEGIN  
  --column headers  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘column name header 1 | column name header 2 | 
  column name header 3 |………..| column name header n’);  
END; /  
  --extract 
  (SELECT UNIQUE temptable.columnname1 || '|' ||  
  temptable.columnname2 || '|' ||                
  ‘columnname3’ || '|' ||               
  ………………                
  temptable.columnnamen '|' 
  FROM   temptable 
  WHERE  temptable.OUTPUT_INDICATOR = 'extract ready');
```

I have tried renaming the destination file name with .csv extension but all the data is getting copied to a single cell in an excel. Could anyone tell me how we modify the above code to extract data to excel file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Build your header line with separators like the extract line, but use commas for all separators.

Answer (score 0):

In cvs you should use separator, that is recognized by your excel for **your locale** 
(e.g. for US it is comma (,) character, in other countries it could be semicolon(;))

Below is your example with comma separated values

```
BEGIN  
  --column headers  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘column name header 1 , column name header 2 , 
  column name header 3 ,……….., column name header n’);  
END; /  
  --extract 
  (SELECT UNIQUE temptable.columnname1 || ',' ||  
  temptable.columnname2 || ',' ||                
  ‘columnname3’ || ',' ||               
  ………………                
  temptable.columnnamen ',' 
  FROM   temptable 
  WHERE  temptable.OUTPUT_INDICATOR = 'extract ready');
```

Comment: Thanks @plirkee, Do we need set colsep like do we need to include something like colsep ','  ?

Comment: @HarishAv if I am not mistaken colsep is for separating columns. Here your query has just one column - as all the values are concatenated together with '||' operand. So I do not see any need for colsep.

Comment: I honestly do not know about how operands work in pl/sql. Actually The problem is when I change the destination file to .csv all the data is getting copied to single cell in the excel but I need this to be copied in the proper excel format. So for this to happen I guess columns should be separated. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: @HarishAv you don't need colsep for the plsql because when you are creating the file you are putting the 'excel column separator' manually by using this || ',' ||. E.g. You have only 1 sql column but for excel that would be translated to many columns. You have to choose correct character as excel (csv) column separator.  Now if you tried my solution and you sill got everything in once cell - then you should replace every ',' with ';' as this would mean that in your country excel uses semicolon to separate columns.  I hope that I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use comma `,` for column separator and `\r\n` for line separator:

```
BEGIN  
  --column headers  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(‘column name header 1 , column name header 2 , 
  column name header 3 ,……….., column name header n’ || '\r\n');  
END; /  
  --extract 
  (SELECT UNIQUE temptable.columnname1 || ',' ||  
  temptable.columnname2 || ',' ||                
  ‘columnname3’ || ',' ||               
  ………………                
  temptable.columnnamen || '\r\n' 
  FROM   temptable 
  WHERE  temptable.OUTPUT_INDICATOR = 'extract ready');
```